# Restoring mysqldump file of another version

Tags: mysql, restore, mysql-error-1064

I am restoring a mysqldump file to another server. The versions are close, so I didn't expect any problems. I get:

```
:/var/backups$ sudo mysql -f -u root -p dbasename < backup.sql 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 542: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''  Current\n          * President/CEO at  Echoingwalls.com\n        * Develope' at line 1
```

Other's solutions with this error message haven't been helpful. How can I detect if my back up is corrupt? I am pretty sure the versions of MySQL have been pretty close (both 5.x).

Any specific instructions on how to restore this would be appreciated.

Comment: I just tried to insert ignores into my back up file with:`sed -e "s/^INSERT INTO/INSERT IGNORE INTO/" < dbackup.sql | mysql -p dbasename`

(but the process stopped at the same place - same error)

Comment: You should probably search your dump for line 542 or `* President/CEO` and see what the line looks like.  There is a reason for the information found in error messages.

Comment: I am exposing my newbie-ness: what commands would I use to search an existing .sql file at the command line? Is there also a delete-row syntax at the command line?

Comment: An .sql file is plain text.  Just open it up with any text editor.  Most text editors support Go to Line Number or searching.

Comment: Another way to do it: `sed -n 542p backup.sql`

Comment: Solved. I just deleted that row, restored the rest of the database, and now I can restore that record (I know what it is, and have a copy)
Thank you for your guidance! @Devon and Bill!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may have an inconsistency between how your systems are escaping single quote;

```
... use near ''  Current\n          * Presi  ....
              ^ Note the addtional quote
```

Do diagnose the problem compare both tables

```
show create table mytable
```

And campare the sql modes

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

For more help find the insert statement in the dump file and post the sql.